# Magento 2 : Get category level

Tags: magento2, product, category-products, category-tree

I want to get the category level in **product/list.phtml** to check

```
if (categorylevel == 1)
{
    hide product list
}else
{
    show product list
}
```

> How can I do that?

**Any helps? Thank in advance.**

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code :

```
<?php
     $level= $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLevel();
     echo $level;
?>
```

hope its work for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper class to get current category information as given below:

```
<?php

namespace Amit\Test\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
        ) {
                $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    public function getCategory() {
        return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory();
    }
}
```

And get the category level in `product/list.phtml` using below code

```
$testHelper = $this->helper('Amit\Test\Helper\Data');
$catLevel = $testHelper->getCategory()->getLevel();
```